# Queue bash script

Tags: bash, concurrency, thread-safety

Suppose I have a bash script that I want at most one instance of at a given time. Suppose the intended behavior for multiple calls to the same bash script is to queue their executions.

Within a single program where the script is analogous to a function, this can be achieved with mutex locks.

How would I approach such a design?

Comment: take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just off the cuff...

Implement a queueing system inside the script.

Have the script attempt to `mkdir` a known and standard directory name.

```
if mkdir /tmp/${0##*/}.Q
then : .. proceed normally
```

`mkdir` is atomic, so only one instance can ever succeed.
If it fails, test to see if it's because the directory already exists.
If it does not, there's a problem, report and abort.
If it succeeds, open a FIFO in that directory named with the PID of the script, and write its command line arguments there. Maybe add the PID.
Then clear the args, fork a child, and `wait`. On SIGCHLD go read the FIFO again. As long as you find stuff, lather/rinse/repeat. When there's no more, shut down.

If runs with args but the dir exists then confirm a copy is already running on another PID, find the FIFO in the dir, write args (& maybe PID) to that, and exit.

If it *has* no args (likely because it's a forked child), read the pipe, set the args, and process them. Confirm that there is a copy running with the PID that matches the FIFO. Delete the FIFO and exit normally when all records are processed.

Haven't tested this at all. Expect to find some flaws.

*OR* just look for the "flagfile" and sleep a bit in a loop until it does not exist, then create it, run normally, and remove it again when done. That doesn't assure *order*, but it does keep more than one copy from running.

Comment: Ah I did not realize mkdir was atomic. Would something like while ! mkdir {} followed by running the script work as a mutex lock simulator (Ordering is not important)? Would touch work better?

Comment: You might want to use `flock`, but `until mkdir foo; do` should work ok.